# Prevent obsolete properties being added to the designer files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, user-controls

In one of the user controls in our project we have an obsolete property looking like :

```
    [Browsable ( false )]
    [Obsolete ( "Not currently supported on this control" )]
    public bool DeferPropertyValueUpdates
```

Every time I edit a form that contains this control, Visual Studio will put this property into the .designer file.

This then causes a warning to be generated, which makes my boss throw things at me.

How can I stop Visual Studio from putting this property in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is what you need

```
[Browsable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(
                            DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe a

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
```

attribute is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am only accepting the other guys response because he needs rep more than you (slightly)! ;-)